# Python - MySQL syntax error

Tags: python, mysql

I tried to make a python command to update mysql on key duplicate

```
sql.run("INSERT INTO snapshots (id,username,data) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data = VALUES(%s)" % (id,user.name,json.dumps(data),json.dumps(data)))
```

It works on data insert but on key duplicate, it throws this error

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/memsql/common/database.py at 166 > (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'{"achievements": {"150": 1448983913.491705, "200": 1448984742.809708, "204": 144\' at line 1')

I have tried `KEY UPDATE data = '%s'`, `KEY UPDATE data = VALUES(%s)` and `KEY UPDATE data = VALUES('%s')` but none of them works.

What exactly did I do wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `%` operator to insert data into the string.  That opens you up to SQL injection and possible string escaping nightmares.  Usually that facility is provided by whatever sql wrapper you're using.  e.g. `cursor.execute(query, param1, param2, ...)`

Comment: @mgilson aside the SQL injection, is there anything wrong with the SQL statement because it works on insert but not on update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the error is json-dumped string with not escaped `"` characters, caused by direct substituting the data into the query.
As @mgilson said, use `cursor.execute()` method and database driver will take care of escaping.

Comment: I guess there is no choice but to swap to MySQL connector instead. Thanks :)